# Should I make a method static that will be used across many aspx.cs files

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a method with the following signature:

```
string GetTableCellValue(DataTable table, string columnName, int rowIndex){}
```

As you might guess, this method returns the value of the cell located at the specified column of the specified row of the specifies table in string format. It turns out that I need this methods almost in all the webpages. Here's my quetion(s):

1. Should I put this method in all the code files or?
2. Should I have it as a static method of some class, like Utilities_Class or?
3. Should I have it as a public NON-STATIC method of some class , like Utilities_Class?

The last 2 choices seem to be better idea. But I don't know which one to choose eventually.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You probably want to create a static method for this. Specifically, an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx):

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static string GetTableCellValue(this DataTable table,
                                           string columnName, int rowIndex)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Now, you can call it like an instance method on your `DataTable` objects:

```
DataTable dataTable = ...;
var value = dataTable.GetTableCellValue("column", row);
```

Comment: obviously check namespace of the `Extensions` class and import it when you want use it. (I miss it sometimes :P)

Answer (score 2):

I would go for the second option as I wont require the instance of the class e.g  Utilities_Class. GetTableCellValue has nothing to do with its data members or methods to making it static is quite reasonable. Make it [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx) to call it just like it exists in DataTable class.

```
public static class DataExtensions
{
    public static string GetTableCellValue(this DataTable table, string columnName, int rowIndex)
    {
        // implementation
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also create it as an extension method, something like:

```
public static class DataExtensions
{
    public static string GetTableCellValue(this DataTable table, string columnName, int rowIndex)
    {
        // implementation
    }
}
```

Comment: Very true @w0lf, I've expanded my answer accordingly

Answer (score 0):

None of those.

I would advise you to define your own Page (let's call it BasePage) that inherits from Page and add the method in the BasePage.

Every page of yours should be an instance of BasePage instead of the regular Page.

**Edit**: 
As Daniel Hilgarth pointed out, extensions are a better choice than what i proposed.
Please, keep this post so that others will understand what not to do :)

Comment: I advise against it. This is a utility method that has nothing to do with a page. Hence it doesn't belong there.

Comment: Why don't you define your own DataTable (extending the existing one) with that method?

Comment: No need. That's what extension methods are for.

Comment: "No need. That's what extension methods are for."
Thanks for the insight.